# Sage X3 SCS ALL Web API

Tags: web-services, sage

I am trying to use the Stock Change Screen Web API for Sage X3.  I have had success using other APIs, but this one is proving difficult.  Example of link that does not help enough is http://www.greytrix.com/blogs/sagex3/2012/10/20/access-sage-x3-data-from-external-applications-through-web-services/.  That link is accurate, just does not help with this specific Web API. All of the other Web APIs I have used, I can simply substitute my values, blank out the key field, and it will create the record I want.  This one will not work that way.  Here is the pertinent information from the WSDL so someone with knowledge will know which API I am using:

```
OBJ=SCS, TRA=ALL, VER=6.30
```

Comment: StackOverflow is no coding service. Please ask a precise question that can be answered.

Comment: Not asking for a service. Trying to find someone who has correctly used this API that can just point me in the right direction. It is Precise for someone who has working knowledge of Sage API.

Comment: I suppose in re-reading this, I did not ask the question that (I felt)was implied:  Could someone demonstrate the proper way to use the Stock Change Screen Web API to create inventory moves?

Comment: I have found out from Sage Support that there is no way to use this API to do what I want.  We ended up having to have Sage write us a custom API.

Comment: It appears that the problem is that the screen cannot have stock data directly entered, but must be selected from a lookup screen which is not possible with Webservices. Surely a manual entry form should be available, if nothing else than for automation. Requiring a custom import for a core process like this is just cash generation.